# Mail.app and accountsd are taking op all CPU Mac OS 10.15

Tags: mail.app, performance, catalina, cpu

I have suddenly (did not see when it is happening and when it is stopping) CPU peaks, which is coming from Mail.app and accountsd all together

i did a screenshot of the activity monitor as well as the console, where, when this spike is happening, it is creating +/- 3500 messages a second, all the same as the one on the Screenshot shows some of it.

Screenshot Activity Monitor : https://bazinga.lu/mail1.png
Screenshot Console : https://bazinga.lu/mail2.png

Most of the messages are like this one:

Connection error changed for account:

this for all mail accounts. Killing all the accounts and readding, or dis/enabling it did not help

Also another strange thing happening is, in the message list, some users (i found out they are in the contacts and have a different string in the contacts entry than in the one they provide in the mail header) will flash every second from one to the other name in this list. It is a flckering which is constant, let's say every second, a bit delayed the further down in the list the mail is.

Current "solution" is to stop the mail.app and restart it, it will be good for up to 10 minutes and it will happen again

any ideas ? It started when upgrading from 10.14 to 10.15

Latest Mac OS Version 10.15.1 (19B88)

Many Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2):

Same here, problem seems to be closed related to 10.15, since on Mojave I've never experienced something like that. Googling around, I found that the problem seems to be due to some "under-the-hood" logic behind account configuration.

Specifically I found that going to

Mail.app -> Settings -> Accounts -> (repeat for each account you have) -> Server Settings:

Disable the option: "Automatically Manage connection settings"

This seems to lower at 0.0 / 0.1 the CPU requirements for accountsd.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Version 10.15.7.
For me the CPU peak was coming from `accountsd` and I was able to handle the problem by logging out from the Apple ID page in Settings, then logging in again.

Comment: I had the same problem on MacOS 10.15.6 and 10.15.7: 6 of the 12 CPU's of my MacBook Pro were running `accountsd` amounting to a CPU usage of up to 500%. Signing out of my Apple Id account resolved the issue. Also, after signing in again, the problem did not return. Thanks @aesop-의섭 for posting this solution!

Comment: This happened for me after a restart on 10.15.7 and only signing in and our of icloud fixed this. Massive waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with `accountsd` process. Mac OS version is 10.15.7
I solved this problem with Disk Utility application. Click First Aid button on all internal HD consistently.